# Koin Libraray Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, koin, koin-scope

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/ekito/koin/org/koin/koin-core/3.0.1/koin-core-3.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Adding this line show error

```
maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/ekito/koin")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/ekito/koin")` anymore as it's now available on `mavenCentral()`.

Just make sure you are also using the new maven group id which [changed](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin#the-koin-projects-maven-group-id-was-previously-orgkoin-its-now-ioinsert-koin-on-maven-central) from `org.koin` to `io.insert-koin`.